# Is an "answer" that is not answering the question and only questioning the facts (=context) stated in the question NAA?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049014/311865) for moderator attention. Disclosure: I am the OP of the relevant question.

The question asks about how to share [Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29) code between [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) and potentially [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) apps. The purpose of the question is to find out how to share Dart code and I believe the question makes that clear. Specifically note that the question does not ask about [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) apps memory usage/consumption or any other resource allocation by Flutter apps. To explain the question motivation, the question states only as a side note that the *Hello, World!* app in Flutter consumes 116 MB of memory (RAM).

[The "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049014/311865) does not try to answer the question (how to share Dart code?). Instead it disputes the statement that the Flutter the *Hello, World!* app consumes 117 MB of memory. In addition to that, based on "answer" author's (now deleted) comment (the "answer" itself is so low quality that it's hard to tell what exactly its author meant). The author really meant that the apps' *bundle size* is less than 116 MB, not its *memory consumption*. That is completely irrelevant in context of the question. Therefore, IMO it is clearly [NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420) (*it should have been a comment instead*) and should be deleted.

Yet, the flag was declined. I might have made a mistake by flagging it for moderator attention (not as "not an answer") and additionally stated that "btw. the answer is also untrue" in description of my flag. The moderator might have focused on that instead on the main reason for flagging it, which is *it does not even try to answer the question*.

Is this "answer" NAA and should it be deleted?

For context, I flagged the answer two times, and these are the responses I got:

**First flag text**:

> Besides being false, it does not answer the question - instead it argues with a side note stated in the question. No evidence or reference is provided (and the answerer's argument is quite obviously incorrect).

**First flag response**:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

**Second flag text:**

> It does not answer my question. The question is "How to share application logic only between iOS and Android using pure Dart (without Flutter)?" and this answer deals with Flutter app SIZE, or possibly memory consumption (not clear from the answer). That is not relevant AT ALL when it comes to "How do I share Dart code". Note: Flagging again as the previous flag decline reason does not apply to it's not an answer flag.

**Second flag response**:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Comment: Moderators don't typically decide if an answer is technically accurate. So long as it's an attempt to answer a question, they're unlikely to delete it. Could you share the exact decline message, and preferably the exact contents of your custom flag? Also, "*That is completelly irrelevant in context of the question. Therefore, IMO it is clearly NAA ...*" is not the right interpretation of the NAA flag. An answer needs to be Not An Answer *regardless* of the question.

Comment: @cigien It's been added as an edit, please review. I understand the answer to the first flag... My bad I have included the note about it being inaccurate. However, with that second flag I make clear the issue is it's NAA. And the moderator's response is still the same (did they even read what I found problematic, or just repeated the previous answer?).

Comment: @cigien Please note that I did not use NAA flag directly - I could not as I did retracted that flag before and opted for "Needs moderator attention" so now the option was disabled. But I got it... This is an answer, kind of just not to my question. So again, is this "answer" OK or should it be deleted from some other reason?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding them, both your flags (in slightly different words) are pointing out that the answer is incorrect, and irrelevant to the question. The response to both your flags are the same, and say that you shouldn't raise flags for that reason. I'm not sure what you're confused by exactly. If you're asking whether the answer should be deleted, that may be the case, but that's up to the community to decide. Moderators don't get involved in this sort of thing, so raising a flag (NAA or otherwise) is inappropriate in these cases.

Comment: @cigien You are right in case of the first flag: It states that answer is incorrect *and* irrelevant to my question. The second flag only states it is *irrelevant* to my question - that's the difference. Based on your comments it should have been declined as well but the reason for declining it should have been different IMO. It does not make sense to decline a flag that does *not* indicate incorrectnes 'because flags should not be used to indicate incorrectness' .

Comment: @cigien Add "Moderators don't get involved in this sort of thing, so raising a flag (NAA or otherwise) is inappropriate in these cases.". Got it and thank you.

Comment: As an alternative to flagging such cases, drop by in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and, provided the answer matches [*satisfies all the rules*](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests) for [del-pls] request, try posting a request there - you'll get a peer review *and* a deletion *if* it is warranted. To second cigien, mods aren't expected to be SMEs. [to avoid potential confusion: **note rule 15** that would make *this particular request* ineligible]

Comment: Note: while someone else would be permitted to post a `[del-pls]` request in SOCVR for such an answer, you, as the author of the question on which the answer was posted, would be considered "involved" in the answer and, thus, not permitted to make requests about that answer or any other answer on your question(s). Requests are not permitted in SOCVR about posts in which you are "involved" (i.e. where you might have a conflict of interest). Please see [SOCVR's FAQ #15](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-no-requests-youre-involved) for a much more detailed description of what is meant by "involved".

Answer (score 6):

I think this answer *could* be interpreted as an attempt to answer the question by disputing the premise of it. In many cases somebody asks a question based on a misconception, false belief or non-trivial mistake, and the most useful way to answer the question is to correct them. If the mistake is common enough, then it is useful to have a Q&A which corrects it.

In this case, the answerer attempted to dispute the premise of your question, but they were factually wrong. In that case their answer can be seen as an attempt to write what would - if it was factually correct - be a useful and right answer. So by that logic it's not Not An Answer. In general the NAA flag is completely orthogonal to the factual or technical accuracy of an answer's content, because it is handled by a moderator who is typically not a subject matter expert capable of judging that. So when flagging for a moderator, it's best to not mention at all whether the answer is false or technically inaccurate.

That said, I think the answerer *should* have posted this as a comment, but mainly because if the answer was actually right then it would have been correcting a mistake too trivial to be worth writing an answer for.

Comment: Re *"non-trivial mistake"*: Why does it matter if it is trivial or not (not a rhetorical question)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen A trivial mistake would fall into the typo category, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, if a question is based on a trivial mistake then it should normally be closed as "not reproducible, unlikely to help future readers".